# User not in sudo list but can still use sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, fedora-17

I am running Fedora 17.

My user was created during the live cd install and has root/admin privileges. Hence, I use the sudo command to perform root actions. E.g

```
sudo iftop
```

I enter my password and it works.

However, when I access

```
sudo visudo
```

My username is not listed.

Can someone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: An ordinary user doesn't have "root" access in linux other than via sudo (or su).  However, your user could be part of a group that has sudo access.  If you do `id`, can you see `adm`, `sudo` or any other admin-like groups - check this in `visudo` too.

Comment: Also check `/etc/sudoers.d` https://serverfault.com/questions/574953/user-not-in-sudoers-but-still-can-use-sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't mean you're already acting as the root user, you'll likely find an entry in the sudoers file for the wheel group, a line that starts with  %wheel, and you'll be in that group (which is stored in the /etc/groups file)

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. By running the command "groups" I can see that I am in the "wheel" group.

Answer (score 0):

To adding to Sirex's response above, here's a [link](http://alien.slackbook.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=linux:admin) with more information about the `wheel` group.

Also, check the man pages for `sudo` and `sudoers` for more information.

Comment: Isn't that just referring to the user called "root"? I tried running sudo with a user that is in the "root" group but not in wheel or listed as an explicit entry in the sudoers list and this user was not able to execute commands using sudo.

Comment: I actually tried testing this by removing the root user from the sudoers list. When it was removed I could still access the sudo list using the command "visudo". But then I tried accessing visudo using the command "sudo visudo" it didn't work. But I when I added root ALL=(ALL) ALL back to visudo I could use the command "sudo visudo" as root.